# sort imput files in pdfbeads

Tags: sort, pdf, images

I'm trying to make a pdf from hundreds of .tif images with `pdfbeads`. I can't make the program use the images in the correct numerical order. For example, during the process I see:

```
Prepared data for processing image-098.tif
Prepared data for processing image-099.tif
Prepared data for processing image-100.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1000.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1001.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1002.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1003.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1004.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1005.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1006.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1007.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1008.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1009.tif
Prepared data for processing image-101.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1010.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1011.tif
Prepared data for processing image-1012.tif
```

With the following command i get the correct one

```
ls -v
```

so I tried

```
pdfbeads $(ls -v) > file.pdf
```

with no results.

Comment: You assume we know the syntax of `pdfbeads`. We do not. Can you please explain it? Also, can we assume your shell is bash?

Comment: Syntax of pdfbeads: `pdfbeads [options] [files to process] > out.pdf`. Yes I use bash. I have narrowed down the problem: if I use `pdfbeads image-101.tif image-1009.tif > a.pdf` pdfbeads uses first the image 1009 than 101. I do not know why this is happening, but it tottally mess up the final pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If count reaches 1000 images, then we have to use 4 digits in all numbers to sort them correctly. This can be done with the rename command:

```
rename image- image-0 *-[0-9][0-9][0-9].tif
```

done!

```
image-0229.tif     image-0487.tif  image-0745.tif  image-1003.tif
image-0230.tif     image-0488.tif  image-0746.tif  image-1004.tif
image-0231.tif     image-0489.tif  image-0747.tif  image-1005.tif
image-0232.tif     image-0490.tif  image-0748.tif  image-1006.tif
image-0233.tif     image-0491.tif  image-0749.tif  image-1007.tif
image-0234.tif     image-0492.tif  image-0750.tif  image-1008.tif
image-0235.tif     image-0493.tif  image-0751.tif  image-1009.tif
image-0236.tif     image-0494.tif  image-0752.tif  image-1010.tif
image-0237.tif     image-0495.tif  image-0753.tif  image-1011.tif
image-0238.tif     image-0496.tif  image-0754.tif  image-1012.tif
image-0239.tif     image-0497.tif  image-0755.tif  image-1013.tif
```

Comment: If you want to report the erroneous sorting of the input files to the `pdfbeads` developers, you can point out that it's [this line in the code](https://github.com/ifad/pdfbeads/blob/7f81be26eced36b12fa2cd6795c57ab4c9230eae/bin/pdfbeads#L191) that is the issue.

Comment: Ok, I will do it. Thanks for all the help.